Balancing of forces after the deformed body comes to equilibrium
We were studying elasticity and the factors responsible for the deformation of the body when a force by external agent is applied. So, while trying to explain the phenomenon that happen at the molecular level my sir said that the internal forces of the structure is responsible to balance out the net external force applied (let's take outwards for this case). But upon thinking about it I wasn't able to find which force exactly would be able to do so. Since nuclear and electrostatic forces would weaken upon increasing the intermolecular distance.
So I was just curious to know which force exactly helps in balancing the net outward external force here.
Can anyone please help me out through this.

Basically it's Van der Waals force,- a pushing force between closely packed atoms electron clouds, which compensates external forces like gravity, etc, and doesn't let solid state object to overlap with itself or other object.

@Agnius I don't have very much knowledge in that background but just to be sure since van der waals force is inversely proportional to the distance. So the amount of van der waals force helping to hold the structure would decrease as we apply force in outward direction. So is van der waals force enough to hold the structure intact.

Sure other electromagnetic bonding is possible too between atoms/molecules in a crystal lattice,- like ionic, covalent or metallic. But overall for crystal keeping it's structure and resisting external pressure mostly responsible is Coulomb force interactions between lattice charges.

@SamarMangla Van der Waals forces are proportional to the inverse of the seventh power of the distance between them.

The resolution lies in the balance (modeled by an interatomic potential) of attractive and repulsive forces in solids. The average intermolecular distance is set by this balance.
If you deform the solid such that the intermolecular distance increases, it’s true that the electrostatic attraction term decreases, as you note. However, the repulsion term decreases more (being a stronger function of the distance), and so the net result is positive intermolecular attraction and a tensile stress that tends to hold the material together and to restore the intermolecular spacing (and material density) back to their equilibrium values.


electrostatic forces would weaken upon increasing the intermolecular
distance

It looks like you are referring to Coulomb's law for the force between electrical charges. But the forces associated with elasticity and Hooke's law are interatomic forces where the force does not follow a simple inverse square of the distance rule as shown in the figure below. Feynman in his physics lectures described it as follows:
If the molecules are pushed only a very small distance closer, or pulled only a very small distance farther than d, the corresponding distance along the curve of Fig. 12–2 is also very small, and can then be approximated by a straight line. Therefore, in many circumstances, if the displacement is not too great the force is proportional to the displacement. This principle is known as Hooke’s law

Hope this helps.
